# HTML data encryption

Tags: html, encryption, media

I have 10-15 basic HTML5 pages which contain images and videos. I am planing to put them on a public server so anyone can access it. Same time I do not want anyone to download and re-use/misuse. **How can I encrypt the media? or whole html page data?**

I have read about Base64 but it does not provide 100% safety. Basically what I understood, Base64 is encoding and not encryption.

Comment: There are proposals as to how this might be done. See [Encrypted Media Extensions](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/encrypted-media/encrypted-media.html). But not much in the way of implementations at present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot both protect and share video, not unless the whole chain (including client) is protected. Even then, there are things like high res camera's, supplied to almost every phone nowadays. The only thing you can do is to make it harder, e.g. by using some kind of flash video that cannot be easily saved. You are thinking of a [DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) scheme.

Base64 does not provide any safety, it's indeed encoding, not encryption. But then, neither will anything else.

Comment: I would love to use Flash platform but all devices do not support flash format...specially ios. So, I have to stick to HTML...How about using SSL...does it protect streaming video and images?

Comment: SSL - or it's successor TLS - does protect video and images, but only in transit (Transport Layer Security, name says it all). Once the video is at the client's computer, it provides exactly zero protection.